# Logging of different steps of a task to a single file in python

Tags: python-2.7, logging

I have a single task with 3 below steps

Step 1 : run an unix command
  Step 2 : run a java command
  Step 3 : trigger a shell script

I want the log file to maintain the success and failure scenarios of above steps along with parameters and timestamp of failure.

I used below sample program

```
    import logging

    logging.basicConfig(
        filename="test.log",
        level=logging.DEBUG,
        format="%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s"
        )


    class Pizza():
        def __init__(self, name, price):
            self.name = name
            self.price = price
            logging.debug("Pizza created: {} (${})".format(self.name, self.price))

        def make(self, quantity=1):
            logging.debug("Made {} {} pizza(s)".format(quantity, self.name))

        def eat(self, quantity=1):
            logging.debug("Ate {} pizza(s)".format(quantity, self.name))

    pizza_01 = Pizza("Sicilian", 18)
    pizza_01.make(5)
    pizza_01.eat(4)

    pizza_02 = Pizza("quattro formaggi", 16)
    pizza_02.make(2)
    pizza_02.eat(2)`
```

Comment: what's not working?

Comment: this is not the expected working of code I want.
I want to log the success and failure of steps one by one into different files.
For example:
Step 1: java command
Step 2 : unix command

The log file should contain the java command and status whether it is failed or not and also the unix command and it's status.

Corresponding timestamps also need to be logged.